# Udacity Self Driving Car Simulator

Tags: python, simulator

I am working on Udacity's self-driving car simulator. I am facing a problem in this when I run the drive.py file with my model as argument model.h5 nothing happens in the simulator.
The model has been trained completely without any errors but still, there is no response from the simulator.
Here is the drive.py python code and a link to the video to show what is actually happening

**drive.py**

```
import argparse
import base64
from datetime import datetime
import os
import shutil

import numpy as np
import socketio
import eventlet
import eventlet.wsgi
from PIL import Image
from flask import Flask
from io import BytesIO

from keras.models import load_model
import h5py
from keras import __version__ as keras_version

sio = socketio.Server()
app = Flask(__name__)
model = None
prev_image_array = None


class SimplePIController:
    def __init__(self, Kp, Ki):
        self.Kp = Kp
        self.Ki = Ki
        self.set_point = 0.
        self.error = 0.
        self.integral = 0.

    def set_desired(self, desired):
        self.set_point = desired

    def update(self, measurement):
        # proportional error
        self.error = self.set_point - measurement

        # integral error
        self.integral += self.error

        return self.Kp * self.error + self.Ki * self.integral


controller = SimplePIController(0.1, 0.002)
set_speed = 30
controller.set_desired(set_speed)

def crop_image(img, img_height=75, img_width=200):
    height = img.shape[0]
    width = img.shape[1]

    y_start = 60
    #x_start = int(width/2)-int(img_width/2)

    return img[y_start:y_start+img_height, 0:width ]#x_start:x_start+img_width]


@sio.on('telemetry')
def telemetry(sid, data):
    if data:
        # The current steering angle of the car
        steering_angle = data["steering_angle"]
        # The current throttle of the car
        throttle = data["throttle"]
        # The current speed of the car
        speed = data["speed"]
        # The current image from the center camera of the car
        imgString = data["image"]
        image = Image.open(BytesIO(base64.b64decode(imgString)))
        image_array = np.asarray(image)
        image_array = crop_image(image_array)
        
        steering_angle = float(model.predict(image_array[None, :, :, :], batch_size=1))

        throttle = controller.update(float(speed))

        print(steering_angle, throttle)
        send_control(steering_angle, throttle)

        # save frame
        if args.image_folder != '':
            timestamp = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S_%f')[:-3]
            image_filename = os.path.join(args.image_folder, timestamp)
            image.save('{}.jpg'.format(image_filename))
    else:
        # NOTE: DON'T EDIT THIS.
        sio.emit('manual', data={}, skip_sid=True)


@sio.on('connect')
def connect(sid, environ):
    print("connect ", sid)
    send_control(0, 0)


def send_control(steering_angle, throttle):
    sio.emit(
        "steer",
        data={
            'steering_angle': steering_angle.__str__(),
            'throttle': throttle.__str__()
        },
        skip_sid=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Remote Driving')
    parser.add_argument(
        'model',
        type=str,
        help='Path to model h5 file. Model should be on the same path.'
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        'image_folder',
        type=str,
        nargs='?',
        default='',
        help='Path to image folder. This is where the images from the run will be saved.'
    )
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # check that model Keras version is same as local Keras version
    f = h5py.File(args.model, mode='r')
    model_version = f.attrs.get('keras_version')
    keras_version = str(keras_version).encode('utf8')

    if model_version != keras_version:
        print('You are using Keras version ', keras_version,
              ', but the model was built using ', model_version)

    model = load_model(args.model)

    if args.image_folder != '':
        print("Creating image folder at {}".format(args.image_folder))
        if not os.path.exists(args.image_folder):
            os.makedirs(args.image_folder)
        else:
            shutil.rmtree(args.image_folder)
            os.makedirs(args.image_folder)
        print("RECORDING THIS RUN ...")
    else:
        print("NOT RECORDING THIS RUN ...")

    # wrap Flask application with engineio's middleware
    app = socketio.Middleware(sio, app)

    # deploy as an eventlet WSGI server
    eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 4567)), app)
```

**problem video link**
https://youtu.be/nP8WH8pM29Q

Comment: please reduce the code so that users can identify the problem easily... https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the socketio version. Use 4.2.1, that should fix your problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Please lower the socketio version, you can check you simulator logs and adjust the version of socketio accordingly